# Which is larger enthalpy or entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

In statistical mechanics, entropy is an extensive property of a thermodynamic system.

Enthalpy a property of a thermodynamic system, is equal to the system's internal energy plus the product of its pressure and volume.

Which is larger enthalpy or entropy?

Comment: So we can say that enthalpy larger than entropy right?

Comment: Please don’t use the phrase “heat content of the system”

Comment: Whichever has the larger value :P. On a more serious note, Ofek's answer explains this well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because enthalpy is measured in joules (it has the dimensions of energy) and entropy is measured in joules per kelvin (it has the dimensions of Boltzmann's constant) then you can't compare what is bigger. It's like asking what is larger: the mass of the earth or the temperature in the sun's core, this question doesn't have a meaning because you can't compare these two.